# Meteor - Trying to automate using data attributes and ReactiveDict

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to automate naming conventions used for a reactive dictionary, but I'm stuck not knowing how to access the reactive dictionary key based on the data attribute I fetched on click.

**Expected**: Use same naming convention for both ReactiveDict keys and data-attribute names on HTML elements so I can fetch the name on the element clicked, take its data-attribute name and automatically know which ReactiveDict key it is because they use the same name.

**Result**: It's not recognizing the naming convention when trying to set or get from the ReactiveDict because... I don't know. I'm guessing it's because when you create a ReactiveDict, you use this convention template.search.set('generic_name', data) but it won't work if I replace 'generic_name' with the data-attribute name (that doesn't include the single quotes) on click.

Please see example code below and advise if you have any questions, request for more info, or funny jokes since we're all trapped at home avoiding the COVID-19 virus :slight_smile:

**home-template.html**

```
<template name="home_template">
    <section class="home-template">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="filter-box">
                <ul>
                    <legend class="sui-category__title">CATEGORY 1</legend>
                    {{#each option in category_one}}
                    <li data-filter-value="{{option.value}}" data-category-name="category_one">
                        <div class="circle">{{formatToNumberWithComma(option.count)}}</div>
                        <h4>{{option.value}}</h4><input id="filter-1-{{get_this(option)}}" type="checkbox" /><label for="filter-1-{{get_this(option)}}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
                    </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
                <span class="more-options">+ More</span>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-box">
                <ul>
                    <legend class="sui-category__title">CATEGORY 2</legend>
                    {{#each option in category_two}}
                    <li data-filter-value="{{option.value}}" data-category-name="category_two">
                        <div class="circle">{{formatToNumberWithComma(option.count)}}</div>
                        <h4>{{option.value}}</h4><input id="filter-2-{{get_this(option)}}" type="checkbox" /><label for="filter-2-{{get_this(option)}}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
                    </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
                <span class="more-options">+ More</span>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-box">
                <ul>
                    <legend class="sui-category__title">CATEGORY 3</legend>
                    {{#each option in category_three}}
                    <li data-filter-value="{{option.value}}" data-category-name="category_three">
                        <div class="circle">{{formatToNumberWithComma(option.count)}}</div>
                        <h4>{{option.value}}</h4><input id="filter-3-{{get_this(option)}}" type="checkbox" /><label for="filter-3-{{get_this(option)}}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
                    </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
                <span class="more-options">+ More</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

**home-template.js**

```
Template.home_template.onCreated(() => {
    const template = Template.instance();

    template.search = new ReactiveDict();
    template.search.set('category_one');
    template.search.set('category_two');
    template.search.set('category_three');
    template.search.set('filter_parameters');
});

Template.home_template.helpers({
    formatToNumberWithComma(number) {
        return format_w_comma(number);
    },
    category_one() {
        const template = Template.instance();
        return template.search.get('category_one')[0].data;
    },
    category_two() {
        const template = Template.instance();
        return template.search.get('category_two')[0].data;
    },
    category_three() {
        const template = Template.instance();
        return template.search.get('category_three')[0].data;
    },
    get_this(option) {
        const query_to_array = [];
        const search_query_word_array = option.value.split(' ');
        const search_query_word_array_count = search_query_word_array.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < search_query_word_array_count; i++) {
            query_to_array[i] = `${search_query_word_array[i]}`;
        }

        const search_query = query_to_array.join('-');
        return search_query;
    },
});

Template.home_template.events({
    'click .home-template label': function (event, template) {
        $(event.currentTarget).parent('li').toggleClass('active');

        const category_clicked = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li')[0].dataset.categoryName;
        const filter_selected = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li')[0].dataset.filterValue;
        const array = template.search.get(category_clicked);

        array.indexOf(filter_selected) === -1 ? array.push(filter_selected) : array.splice(array.indexOf(filter_selected), 1);
        template.search.set(category_clicked, array);

        const filter_parameters = {
            filters: {
                all: [{
                    category_one: template.search.get('category_one'),
                },
                {
                    category_two: template.search.get('category_two'),
                },
                {
                    category_three: template.search.get('category_three'),
                },
                ],
            },
        };

        template.search.set('filter_parameters', filter_parameters);
    },
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please also add the template helpers to the code example?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I just added the helpers to the code. Let me know if you require anything further for this.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure, that `category_clicked` is actually one of `['category_one', 'category_two', 'category_three']` ?

Comment: By the way when creating a new project with your above example I won't be able to get anything running because it's missing initial data for the three cateogries. Thus I am not able to get anywhere to click the `label` in order to trigger the event you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You data keys are working, you actually set the data here:

```js
const category_clicked = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li')[0].dataset.categoryName
const filter_selected = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li')[0].dataset.filterValue
const array = template.search.get(category_clicked)

array.indexOf(filter_selected) === -1 
  ? array.push(filter_selected) 
  : array.splice(array.indexOf(filter_selected), 1)

template.search.set(category_clicked, array)
```

Consider the following data:

```js
template.search.set('category_one', [
  {
    data: [
      {
        value: 'some value here',
        count: 100
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

and `category_clicked` to be `category_one` and `filter_selected` to be `some value here` then the code above will result in the following data:

```js
[
    {
      data: [
        {
          value: 'some value here',
          count: 100
        }
      ]
    },
    'some value here'
]
```

I am not sure how you further process this data but this shows your reactive data is working. The data updated in the helper right after your clicked the `label`.

Comment: I agree, the data is definitly working and reactive, the thing I'm discovering is that I can't use reactive data when trying to set or get a reactive dictionary name. For example, you have to normally set a dictionary name like this template.dictionary.set('something') but since I'm trying to automate it, it doesn't seem to like this, template.dictionary.set(clicked_name). Any ideas how to make the setting and getting work without traditional naming convention, ie ('something') in quotes instead of (no_quote_variable))

Comment: Actually you do this in your event example and as I just showed it works or do I get this totally wrong here?